# Best way to store large lists in a dynamo DB table to optimize for decode time

Tags: python, list, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to store large vectors of floats as one of my columns in my dynamodb table.  I know that a pervious answer on here used an numpy array .toString() to store it and then decoded with np.frombuffer(x,dtype=float).  I can not use this method however as I need to use only python standard libraries.

I am currently using `','.join(map(str, q))` where q is my list of floats to encode my vector.  Then to decode it I am splitting the string.  I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to encode the list using standard libraries to optimize for decode time.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can’t use the list of number type that DynamoDB already supports?

Comment: When I attempt to create the attribute as a list using python boto3 I get the error ```Value 'L' at 'attributeDefinitions.3.member.attributeType' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [B, N, S]```.

Comment: The message means that the members of the list are not a Boolean, String, or Number. That’s because boto3 expects a DynamoDB Number to be represented as a python `Decimal`, so you’ll have to convert the list of floats to a list of `Decimal`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize your vector object using [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and store the [binary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes.Binary) in DynamoDB.

When you retrieve from Dynamo, use Pickle or [`numpy.load`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) to transform again into a vector.

> Beware that DynamoDB has a limit of 400kb for each item. You mentioned 'large vectors', make sure you can stay within this limit. If not, consider another database or maybe store on [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).